# Java BitSet size() behavior

Tags: java, arrays, bitset

I was planning on using BitSet to manipulate the bits in a byte[] since a library exists.

However, it seems after creating a BitSet from a byte[], the minimum size of BitSet is 64, otherwise it ends up zero. 
Is there a requirement that there must be 8 bytes? 
Also, a byte[] that is equivalent to zero will always show up with zero size. I assumed it would still output the size of the byte array?

ie.

```
BitSet bs1 = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1});  // bs1.size() == 64
BitSet bs2 = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}); // bs2.size() == 64
BitSet bs3 = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1});  // bs3.size() == 128
BitSet bs4 = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});  // bs4.size() == 0
System.out.print(bs1.size() + " " + bs2.size() + " " + bs3.size() + " " +  bs4.size());
```

I'll probably end up writing my own function but I'm curious as to why this happens.

Thanks!

Comment: As well as reading the Javadoc, the source code is readily available: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/BitSet.java -- note that this implementation stores the bits as an array of `long`. But - think carefully before you rely on implementation details. The behaviour described in the docs is all that's guaranteed to remain true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read the javadoc:

[size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size()):
*Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values.*

Thing is: the BitSet pre-allocates space; and that is what size() tells you about! It does **not** tell you how many bits exactly you "put" into it!

In other words: the BitSet starts with 64 "empty" bits; and as soon as you "put in" a value that requires more than those 64; you go to 128 bits of "allocation". Also note that size() depends on your JDK's implementation of `BitSet`.

You might want to look into [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length()) resp. [valueOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[])); probably that will help you solving your problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer (read the Javadoc!) but I suggest also mentioning `length()` and quoting the part about size being implementation-dependent.

Comment: I did read the part about size(), however, I didn't read the javadoc on valueOf() which shows the original BitSet size and the fact that it can't be equal to zero. Thanks!

Comment: @eggplant Updated my answer accordingly. If your problem is resolved; feel free to accept my answer then ;-)